# Does Shorted if evaluate statement twice?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
int num = (map.get(result.getNumber()) != null ? map.get(result.getNumber()) : 0);
```

My question is:

Do `map.get` performed twice (one for the evaluation and one for the placement)?

My goal is to reduce the `get` statement into single call.

Note: `result.getNumber` is nullable.

Comment: Yes, it will be executed twice, if the condition is `true`

Comment: any way to reduce the `get` into single call?

Comment: store it into a variable

Comment: As simple as that :) .Got it. thanks

Comment: The compiler doesn't do any optimization.. JIT might cache it, but there is no guarantee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `map.get` gets called twice. Just create a local variable use it to store the value.

```
Integer x = map.get(result.getNumber());
int num = (x != null ? x : 0);
```

Comment: No need for parenthesis

Answer (score 3):

In java 8 the [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) method is added to the `Map` interface. If you don't store `null` as value in the map, you can use the following code:

```
int num = map.getOrDefault(result.getNumber(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Store this into a variable like this :-

```
Integer tempVar = map.get(result.getNumber());

int num = (tempVar != null ? tempVar  : 0);
```

Comment: tempVar might get thrown, map can return null.

Comment: Ok then we can define `int` to `Integer`.